# Error while trying to send a Post request. I'm using Nodejs along with MongoDB for the project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, mern

I'm trying to build a small social networking site using the MERN stack. I have installed Nodejs along with a few dependencies. When I try to post data using Postman (this is on the login page - name, email, password have to be entered), the terminal shows this error and Postman also shows error. What is the issue here?

```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at parse (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\devconnector\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
>     at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\devconnector\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>     at invokeCallback (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\devconnector\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>     at done (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\devconnector\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\devconnector\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
>     at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

I'm sending the following token:

```
{name : "John Doe", email : "example@gmail.com, password : "somepassword"}
```

Comment: `Unexpected token n in JSON`. You need to show us the JSON you are sending.

Comment: Updated it. Thanks!

Comment: And sure enough, that is not valid JSON. The "keys" need to be in quotes and you seem to be missing one quote at the end of your email value. You can find plenty of JSON validators online to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'm new to this and I made a rookie mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the keys in quotes. regardless of the unexpected token, this error usually means that what you are trying to send is not valid JSON. try this:

```
{"name": "John Doe", "email": "example@gmail.com", "password": "somepassword"}
```